# N-th root of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Given $n \in \Bbb Z$ and a function $g(x)$, is it possible to find an $f(x)$ such that $f^n(x) = g(x)$ where $(a \circ b)(x) = a(b(x))$ given such a function exists?

---

Examples: 
Given
$$g(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
5 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 1
\end{pmatrix}, n = 2$$
One solution is
$$f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
3 & 1 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$$

Or if $g(x) = x^4+2x^3+4x^2+3x+3$ and $n = 2$ then $f(x)$ could be $x^2 + x + 1$

Comment: Your matrices are constants so $f^n(x)=f(x)=$ constant.  Perhaps you mean the action of the matrices on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Those matrices are a notation for functions. For example, in g(x), 1 -> 5, 2 -> 3, 3 - > 4 ...

Comment: Since there are no answers to your query, let me mention that the injective ones among your first class of functions are referred to as permutations; they form finite groups; and one does look a lot at the orders of the elements, i.e., for what $n$ does one have $\sigma^n=i$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation and $i$ is the identity.  That tells us that certain powers $\sigma^k$ are powers of other such powers.  See e.g., Lang *Undergraduate Algebra* ch. 2, section 6.